# Good graphics card for TV-Out

Tags: linux, graphics

I am looking for a graphics card (AGP) with a TV-Out (SVideo or Composite) that is not a PITA with X. I guess it depends on the driver/X-Server.

The card needs to be small and should not have a huge cooler mounted beause it is supposed to be plugged into a shuttle case. The on board VIA UniChrome chipsets TV-Out is supposed to play well with Linux with the openChrome-Driver (www.openchrome.org seems to be down), but I could not get it to work.

So this are the conditions:

- Linux (current Ubuntu?)
- AGP
- short card
- small cooler (possibly passive or really quiet)
- TV-Out playing well with Linux and X
- card should still be available through second hand sources (eBay?)

Do you have any recommendations and/or experiences to share?

Comment: I guess any NVidia card would work. But I don't have an old one laying around to try it. BTW: http://openchrome.org works again :)

Comment: So by TV-out what exactly do you mean?  Coaxial output?  Would hdmi/dvi out suffice as LCDs have Hdmi and some you can find with dvi. ?

Comment: Composite or SVideo. DVI or HDMI would be too easy ;-)

Comment: Meaning Cinch or Whatever those SVideo Plugs are called (look like PS/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in the days of Pentium IIs and 3s I had several AGP Nvidia cards, from Riva TNT, GForce 2, GForce 3, GForce 4 MX ... all worked quite well on TV out. In those days I had to manually configure X and restart the computer for TV out to work, but know you can just use the "xrandr" command with a couple of parameters and everything works fine.